# order of a group generated by $(1357)(2468)$ and $(12)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I want to find a order of group $G$ generated by $\tau=(1357)(2468)$ and $\sigma=(12)$ in $S_8$.

My idea is following. Since $\sigma\tau\sigma^{-1}\tau^{-1}=(12)(34)$ , the order of $[G,G]$ is $2$. The quotient group $G/[G,G]$ is abelian, so any element of $[G,G]$ can be written as the form $\sigma^m\tau^n$, where $m=0,1 ~~n=0,1,2,3$. So the order of $G/[G,G]$ is $2\times 4=8$. Finally the order of $G$ is $|G|=|G/[G,G]|\times [G,G]=8\times 2=16$.

But listing the elements of $G$ by computing the order of $G$ looks like bigger than $16$. Where am I wrong? What is the order of $G$? Please give me some advice.

**Edit**:I understood what I misunderstood. The group generated by $(12)(34)$ is not normal. Because of $\tau(\sigma\tau\sigma^{-1}\tau^{-1})\tau^{-1}=(34)(56)$ and $\sigma(\sigma\tau\sigma^{-1}\tau^{-1})\sigma^{-1}=(12)(34)$, the minimum normal subgroup which contains $(12)(34)$ is the group $<(12)(34),(34)(56)>$. So the order of $G$ is $8\times 4$ =$32$.

Comment: What is $\tau^2 \sigma \tau^{-2}$?

Comment: @Mark Bennet:It is $(5,7)$.

Comment: Are you sure? Note: you haven't captured the whole of the commutator subgroup, for a start.

Comment: @MarkBennet: $\tau^2\sigma\tau^{-2}=(15)(37)(26)(48)(12)(15)(37)(26)(48)=(56)$. Is there something wrong?  Hmm. $G/<\sigma\tau\sigma^{-1}\tau^{-1}>$ is abelian because of $\tau\sigma=\sigma\tau$. So I think $[G,G]\subset <\sigma\tau\sigma^{-1}\tau^{-1}>$.

Comment: And so $(1 2)(5 6)$ is a commutator

Comment: @MarkBennet: Certainly. Then are there other commutators? I wonder $[G,G]$ is $4$.

Comment: @MarkBennet: Thank you for your hint. I edited my answer.

Comment: You need to do quite a lot more thinking about this. I am not sure that your method is helping you.

Comment: The order of this group is larger than $32$. Hint: the group is imprimtive with blocks $\{1,2\}$, $\{3,4\}$, $\{5,6\}$, $\{7,8\}$.

Comment: Looks like $C_2^4\rtimes C_4$ to me. The normal subgroup $C_2^4$ is generated by $(12)$ and its conjugates by powers of $\tau$. Then $\tau$ generates the non-normal subgroup $C_4$.

Comment: Certainly the order of this group is larger than $32$. Indeed Gap says the order of this group is $64$. But how do I find the order by myself?